# c++ factory: extend the register via run time loaded plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, factory

**In short:** I want to load a shared library in which I extend a Factory map, without having to recompile the base program. I search and search, but don't understand how to go further: dlopen ? (but i don't get the dlsym things) . Something else ?
Provided I give all the custom libraries needed for my program, can i "re-link" everything by adding plugin.so ? What happens if my code need boost, and the user doesn't have boost-devel ?

**Details:** Let's say i have a code running fine with an object factory, for instance:

```
class Voxel_Factory {
public:
    static std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Voxel_Factory> >* Voxel_Factories;
protected:

    static std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Voxel_Factory> >* get_map(){
        if(!Voxel_Factories){
            Voxel_Factories = new std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Voxel_Factory> >;
        }
        return Voxel_Factories;
    }
public:
    virtual boost::shared_ptr<Voxel> create_voxel(foo bar) = 0 ;
};


template<class V>
class Spe_Voxel_Factory : public Voxel_Factory {
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<Voxel> create_voxel(foo bar){
        return boost::shared_ptr<Voxel>(new V(bar));
    }
};


template<class V>
class Spe_Voxel_Register : public Spe_Voxel_Factory<V> {
public:
    Spe_Voxel_Register(const std::string &s){
        Voxel_Factory::get_map()->insert(
                std::make_pair(s,
                               boost::shared_ptr<Voxel_Factory>(new Spe_Voxel_Factory<V>) ) );
    }
};
```

And i register my classes with :

```
Spe_Voxel_Register<Voxel_Cauchy> Voxel_Cauchy::reg("cauchy");
```

etc etc.
I already have a fully working code.

Now I would like to have a plugin system. For instance let's say that all the files used for `Voxel_Cauchy` are in fact developped somewhere else: someone uses the include of the main code, and generate a library `voxel_cauchy.so`, and place it in a specic directory: `plugins_folder`. I did it for testing purposes, i can create said voxel_cauchy.so file without problem.

**Question:** What should i do in my main code, so that it looks into `plugins_folder` and update correctly my factory map, so I can call :

```
(*Voxel_Factory::Voxel_Factories)[voxel_to_create]->create_voxel(bar)
```

where voxel_to_create="cauchy" ?

Any hint or well expained reference link is welcome. I'm using cmake on Linux, but a cross platform solution would be even better.

I tried in google "c++ how to extend factory map in a plugin", "c++ load shared lybrary at run time object factory", but I can't find a case similar to mine, despite i made my factory by looking at exemple on the net.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can load the shared library with LoadLibrary. 
The process of loading a shared library starts the initialization o global vars that means for C++ object calling the costructor. 
In the shared library you can make a class Init :

```
class Init
{
public:
    Init()
    {
        Spe_Voxel_Register<Voxel_Cauchy> Voxel_Cauchy::reg("cauchy");
        Spe_Voxel_Register<Voxel_Cauchy2> Voxel_Cauchy::reg("cauchy2");
            ...
    }
};

Init init1;
```

Remind that your library and the plugin library must be compiled with the same compiler e use the same c / c++ runtime.

Comment: hi. I'm on Linux (i edited my question). But for the sake of interest, i don't get what constructor you are talking about.

Comment: Hi, I added a better explanation of using costructor to populate your factory